# Adding a column based on another dataframe when merging is not possible

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

My first dataframe (same `name` and `object` might appear multiple times):

```
df_1=
     name      object     number1      number2 
0      n1          o1         0.0          1.0
1      n1          o2         1.0          1.0
2      n2          o1         0.0          1.0
3      n3          o3         1.0          0.0
...
```

My second dataframe might not contain all the `objects` that appear in the first dataframe:

```
df_2=
     value1     value2      number3      object   
0     90.10      40.15          Yes          o1        
1     80.30      92.16           No          o3        
2     20.57      93.69           No          o4        
3     40.60      94.32          Yes          o5  
...
```

I want to append the `number3` column to the first dataframe, where `Yes` is converted to `1.0` and `No` is converted to `0.0`, but ignore the rows where we don't have any info about the `object`. So it would be:

```
     name      object     number1      number2     number3
0      n1          o1         0.0          1.0         1.0
1      n2          o1         0.0          1.0         1.0
2      n3          o3         1.0          0.0         0.0
...
```

For the convertion I'd just do:

```
df_2.number3.replace(to_replace=['No', 'Yes'], value=[0.0, 1.1])
```

But then I can't just `merge` on `object` because they are not identical. **Is it possible to search for the `number3` of the `objects` which are in `df_2`, append it, and delete the rest of the rows?**

Comment: do you want to do an inner join or left join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to do a join/merge on the `object` column:

````
df1.merge(df2,on=['object']).replace(to_replace={'number3':['No', 'Yes']}, value={'number3':[0.0, 1.0]})```
````

Comment: Thank you, didn't know it was so easy! I just wish the columns that I didn't need (`value1` and `value2`) could also be ignored automatically, because in reality there are many more. In this case I would just reduce `df_2` to the necessary columns and then merge.

Comment: You're welcome. You can select a subset of columns from df2 simply by `df2[cols]` where `cols` is a list of column names